# VBA to move cursor down to next row that has a value in column A?

Tags: excel, vba

Column A has values in some rows, blank in others.

I'm in some *other* column. In the row I am in, column A is blank.

I would like a macro which will move my cursor down - remaining in the current column - until it is on a row where column A is **not** blank.

This seems easy, but I know no VBA. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub MoveDownBasedOnColumnA()

  Dim CurCell As Range
  Set CurCell = ActiveCell

  Dim CurCellInA As Range
  Set CurCellInA = Me.Columns("A").Cells(CurCell.Row)

  If IsEmpty(CurCellInA.Offset(1, 0).Value) Then
    CurCell.EntireColumn.Cells(CurCellInA.End(xlDown).Row).Select
  Else
    CurCell.EntireColumn.Cells(CurCellInA.Row + 1).Select
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That threw "invalid use of the 'me' keyword" ... but I got rid of the 'Me.' and now it works!

Thanks so much!

Comment: @dmd: That is because you put it in a module, whereas I meant it to be in a worksheet, where `Me` represent the sheet the code is in. Without `Me` it means "On the active sheet", which is probably what you wanted anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub a()
  i = ActiveCell.Row
  ret = i
  j = ActiveCell.Column
  While (Cells(i, 1).Value = "" And i < 16000)
    i = i + 1
  Wend
  If (i = 16000) Then i = ret
  Application.Goto Reference:=Cells(i, j)
 End Sub
```

Controlled "runaway" when you are bellow the column A used cells limit